# multiple var array = document.getElementsByName('pick1');

Tags: javascript

This works fine in pick1

how do I add pick2 pick3 and pick4

var array = document.getElementsByName('pick1');

Comment: hey!!! what are you looking for.. explan clearly.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   function callRandom(){
                var array = document.getElementsByName('pick1');

   var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

   array[randomNumber].checked = true;
}




    document.getElementById('tb').value = Random()
</script>

Comment: has row 1 2 3 and 4 how to get random on all 4 on click

Comment: var array = document.getElementsByName('pick1');  works good on pick1 row

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```js
function myFunction(value) {
  alert(value);
  var array = document.getElementsByName('pick'+value); 
  var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10); 
  //array[randomNumber].checked = true; } 
//  document.getElementById('tb').value = Random() 
}
```

```html
 <button name="pick1"  onclick="myFunction('1')" type="text" value="Michael">pick1</button><br>
  <button name="pick2"  onclick="myFunction('2')" type="text" value="Michael">pick2</button><br>
```

I think your trying this one i guess..

onclick of the button or div we have to pass a parameter for our identify.
then we can execute our code based on the parameter .